# SQL Counting values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fairly new to SQL and need a quick answer. I have been looking for most of today and need a quick answer so I apologize if this is fairly basic. I am looking for a way to 'summarize' the columns from this query.

```
SELECT 
    Count(case when [BatchNumber] < '100' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
    Count(case when [BatchNumber] like '22%' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
    Count(case when [BatchNumber] like '33%' then 1 else 0 end) as C,
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE [Date] between '2012-01-03' and '2012-01-05'
Group by [Date]
```

Data in the column is similar to:

```
Date             Batchnumber
2012-01-03       1               
2012-01-03       2                
2012-01-03       3              
2012-01-03       4               
2012-01-03       2201
2012-01-03       2202
2012-01-03       3301
2012-01-03       3302
2012-01-03       3303
2012-01-05       1
2012-01-05       2
2012-01-05       3
2012-01-05       4
2012-01-05       5
2012-01-05       3301
2012-01-05       3302
2012-01-05       3303
2012-01-05       3304
```

Looking for output something a long the lines of:

```
Date            A          B          c
2012-01-03      4          2          3
2012-01-05      5          0          4
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: Rolling this back as I did not present my initial problem correctly. The info provided does answer the initial post.

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN...` ?

Comment: On a side note: Better change `'12-01-05'` to `'2012-01-05'` in order to be sure it gets interpreted correctly.

Comment: But now your query does not include [Date] in the column list while your "output" does. And note that if order of rows matters (and it usually does), your query MUST have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - yeah that was a typo. sorry.

Comment: The now altered query with `COUNT` doesn't lack the `GROUP BY` anymore, but has the problem that both 0 and 1 are not null, so both get counted. `COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is hence the same as `COUNT(*)`. You want `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`instead or `COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` or short `COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END)`.

Comment: I think I did not put the source data example in properly. Let me try to update that to give a better idea as to what he data. I get that in a simple table these should work. My table is much larger and complex. I over simplified it. Will edit to see if I can get a better representation and what I get when I run the query. Maybe a new post might be in order to not confuse.

Comment: I agree; a new request would be advisable. I would even roll back the request above to its original state, so future readers see what the answers refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, counting the columns and grouping by date

```
SELECT
        [date],
        sum(case when [BatchNumber] < '100' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
        sum(case when [BatchNumber] like '22%' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
        sum(case when [BatchNumber] like '33%' then 1 else 0 end) as C
    FROM [Database].[dbo].[Transaction]
    WHERE [Date] between '2012-01-03' and '2012-01-05'
    GROUP BY [Date]
    ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: `GROUP BY [Date]` is the correct solution. You should also show the date in the select list and order by it. `COUNT(SUM(...))` however makes no sense. Just `SUM(...)` is correct. At last: `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have the group by in the query, I missed it in my initial post.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want the `distinct`, and you need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Date,
       sum(case when [BatchNumber] < '100' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when [BatchNumber] like '22%' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
       sum(case when [BatchNumber] like '33%' then 1 else 0 end) as C,
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE [Date] between '2012-01-03' and '12-01-05'
GROUP BY Date;
```

The `case` expressions returns either `0` or `1`, so the maximum distinct values are `2`.

Comment: How does one do that count without the case? I have not been able to get a count without? If I take the case info out I get: count([BatchNumber] < '100' ) as A...which give an error in syntax.

Comment: @BrianM . . . Use the `case` expression if you want conditional logic.